# What is the meaning of function`->decltype()`

Tags: c++, decltype, trailing-return-type

I've seen this one function I have no idea what's going on here:

```
template <typename Container>
auto MaxElement(Container &c,int num_of_el)->decltype(c[0]){
    int index=0;
    for(int i=1;i<num_of_el;i++)
        if(c[i]>c[index])
            index=i;
    return c[index];
}
```

This here is the main part of the program:

```
int main(){
    int a=7;
    vector<decltype(a)> v;
    v.push_back(a);
    a=10;
    v.push_back(5);
    cout<<v[0]<<" "<<v[1]<<endl;

    MaxElement(v,v.size())=10;
    cout<<v[0]<<" "<<v[1]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't have a problem understanding how MaxElement function works, but rather with things like `->decltype(c[0])`? What does that do? Also how can we do something like `MaxElement(v,v.size())=10`, what happens here?

Comment: technically, it's an operator keyword, not a function. Kind of like sizeof

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie in the title I meant function and that operator added to a function, not that `->decltype()` is a function, but I understand where the confusion is coming from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `->decltype(c[0])`? What does that do?

In combination with `auto` as the return type, it declares the return type of the function to be of the same type as `c[0]`, which is an `int&`.

In this case, it means that the type of the function has the same type as a reference to an element in the `Container`.

This is to help C++11 compilers which can't deduce this with just `auto`.

A simplified example:

This doesn't work in C++11:

```cpp
template<typename Container>
auto foo(Container& c) {                       // auto is `int` in >= C++14 
    return c[0];
}
```

But this does:

```cpp
template<typename Container>
auto foo(Container& c) -> decltype(c[0]) {     // auto is `int&`
    return c[0];
}
```

---

> Also how can we do something like `MaxElement(v,v.size())=10`, what happens here?

In a function returning a non-`const` reference to an object, you can assign to that object like any other.

Note that `auto` (without the trailing `decltype(C[0])` in C++14 and forward) will *not* return a reference to the returned object. It'll return it *by-value* - and then the assignment would not compile.

Comment: Doesn't `return c[index]` already do that? Also what about asigning value to a function, the second part of my question?

Comment: @bb_823 I added explanations for those things.

Comment: Nooooo! You should be downvoting, deleting and cursing the asker's family name for a thousand generations for having the temerity to ask two things in one question! Now they will learn the wrong life lesson, and soon they'll be doing hard drugs and murdering people!

Comment: @user4581301 :-D :-D I _was_ about to do just that, but since it connected rather nicely to the points about returning references with `auto`, I let that slide. I was about to go into `auto&` and `decltype(auto)` too ... but had to stop somewhere. :)

Comment: Note also that this form allows SFINAE :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 So many things to add :-)